# Cannot update Boolean Array in Room database

Tags: java, android, android-room, dao, android-database

I'm trying to **update** a Boolean array in android room database but it throws this error

`E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "?": syntax error in "UPDATE alarm_table SET mDaysOfWeekArr=?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? WHERE mAlarmId=?"`

Query:(AlarmDao.java)

```
    @TypeConverters({Converter.class})
    @Query("UPDATE alarm_table SET mDaysOfWeekArr=:daysOfWeekArr WHERE mAlarmId=:alarmId")
    void updateRecAlarmStatus(Boolean[] daysOfWeekArr, int alarmId);
```

**When Inserting / Reading the Boolean array correct values are saved in db (Using Query)**

```
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(AlarmEntity alarmEntity);
```

Room Db Repository(AlarmRepository.java)

```
    public void updateRecAlarmStatus(final Boolean[] daysOfWeekArr, final int alarmId) {
        databaseWriteExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                alarmDao.updateRecAlarmStatus(daysOfWeekArr, alarmId);
            }
        });
    }
```

Calling above function with onClick from recyclerView and reading data from entity using getters and changing values in Boolean[]

```
daysOfWeek[1] = true;
daysOfWeek[5] = true
ar.updateRecAlarmStatus(daysOfWeekArr, alarmId);
```

Entity Class: (AlarmEntity.java)

```
@Entity(tableName = "alarm_table")
public class AlarmEntity {

    // ID used to disable / enable / delete alarms
    @PrimaryKey
    private int mAlarmId;

    // Trigger time for alarm
    private long mAlarmTime;
    private boolean mAlarmEnabled;

    @TypeConverters({Converter.class})
    private Boolean[] mDaysOfWeekArr;

......
...... }
```

TypeConverter

```
public class Converter {

    // Used by AlarmEntity Boolean[] mDaysOfWeek

    @TypeConverter
    public static Boolean[] fromString(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<Boolean[]>() {
        }.getType();
        Log.e("Converter: ", "fromString Called");
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromBoolean(Boolean[] list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Log.e("Converter: ", "fromString Called");
        return gson.toJson(list);
    }

}
```

This is my first time asking on stackoverflow.. Please ask if more info/code is required

***EDIT:***

After fetching one alarmEntity object from db and modifying its values
I'm able to save the changes using inbuilt @Update query

but this query does not work... I'm sure below  `SET mDaysOfWeekArr=:daysOfWeekArr`
is wrong but I don't know how to fix it

```
    @TypeConverters({Converter.class})
    @Query("UPDATE alarm_table SET mDaysOfWeekArr=:daysOfWeekArr WHERE mAlarmId=:alarmId")
    void updateRecAlarmStatus(Boolean[] daysOfWeekArr, int alarmId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mDaysOfWeekArr` is stored as `TEXT` in SQLite, so you can't do an `UPDATE alarm_table SET mDaysOfWeekArr=:daysOfWeekArr WHERE mAlarmId=:alarmId` with a `Boolean[]`, hence you get that error.

I'd change your Dao method to be `void updateRecAlarmStatus(String daysOfWeekArr, int alarmId)`, and do your JSON conversion before the calling of this method.

EDIT: Also it doesn't seem that Room is able to use `TypeConverters` when the Dao method has a `@Query` annotation.

Comment: Type converters are used with @Query